# TensorFlow2: ResNet50 - ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, resnet

I am trying to use Transfer Learning using ResNet-50 in TensorFlow2 and Keras on CIFAR-10 dataset which has (32, 32, 3) images.

The default ResNet-50's first conv layer uses a filter size of (7, 7) with stride = 2, the resulting CIFAR-10 is reduced too much spatially here which is to be avoided. As a 'hack', the images are attempted to be upscaled from (32, 32) to (224, 224). The code is:

```
import tensorflow.keras as K

# Define KerasTensor as input-
input_t = K.Input(shape = (32, 32, 3))

res_model = K.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top = False,
    weights = "imagenet",
    input_tensor = input_t
)

# Since CIFAR-10 dataset is small as compared to ImageNet, the images are upscaled to (224, 224)-
to_res = (224, 224)

model = K.models.Sequential()
model.add(K.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image, to_res))) 
model.add(res_model)
model.add(K.layers.Flatten())
model.add(K.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(K.layers.Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Choose an optimizer and loss function for training-
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.1, momentum = 0.9)

model.compile(
    # loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    loss = loss_fn,
    # optimizer = K.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
    optimizer = optimizer,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(
    x = X_train, y = y_train,
    batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 10,
    validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
    # callbacks=[check_point]
    )
```

To which I get the error:

> Epoch 1/10 WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None,
> 32, 32, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32,
> 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1',
> description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an
> input with incompatible shape (None, 224, 224, 3).
>
> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> 2     x = X_train, y = y_train,
> 3     batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 10,
> ----> 4     validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
> 5     # callbacks=[check_point]
> 6     )
>
> 9 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
> 976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> --> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> 978             else:
> 979               raise
>
> ValueError: in user code:
>
> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer resnet50: expected
> shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(None, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: You setup Resnet to take 32x32 images, not 224x224 images.

Answer (score 0):

The input of the model is still (32, 32, 3)

```
input_t = K.Input(shape = (32, 32, 3))
```